# Run $(Linux commnad) in a Python subprocess.run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

I run:

```
proc = subprocess.run(["echo", "$(echo 1111dGUv+rG551123eFwBhCMde6BIS90c3AAAAA= | base64 -d)"], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.stdout)
```

Got:

```
b'$(echo 1111dGUv+rG551123eFwBhCMde6BIS90c3AAAAA= | base64 -d)\n'
```

But wish to have `$(echo 1111dGUv+rG551123eFwBhCMde6BIS90c3AAAAA= | base64 -d)` executed and then passed to `echo` within a subprocess.run. So the result could be:

```
�]ute/����]v��p�u�!/tsp
```

How could this be achieved in subprocess.run() ?

Comment: Why can't you decode it using python `base64` library?

Comment: Using `subprocess` for this could be very dangerous due to shell injection

Comment: Is there some compelling reason to create unnecessary processes and dependencies on external binaries rather than using the built-in Python `base64` which is part of the standard library?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah, there is a reason, since Python interpret base64 as bytes in a bit different form than Linux bash shell does, which therefore causes a problem when running decoded python bytes inside a shell, for example \x00 aka NULL bytes is not supported by bash and therefore should be escaped. That's why I need to decode base64 in a shell directly, instead of doing that in Python.

Comment: @jvx8ss Yeah, shell=True is dangerous, however, it's only causing problems when User defines what to run (user input as a case), but my program doesn't allow to do so and therefore is injection safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `shell=True` argument to the `subprocess.run()` function, like this:

```
proc = subprocess.run('echo "$(echo 1111dGUv+rG551123eFwBhCMde6BIS90c3AAAAA= | base64 -d)"', 
                      shell=True, 
                      check=True, 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(proc.stdout)
```

Comment: your example was first! and does what I need, voteup and accepting

Answer (score 3):

Use `shell=True`, and You don't need this extra `echo` in this case.

```py
proc = subprocess.run(["echo 1111dGUv+rG551123eFwBhCMde6BIS90c3AAAAA= | base64 -d"], check=True, shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(proc.stdout)
```

You can also make this pipe in Python like so:

```py
echo = subprocess.Popen(('echo', '1111dGUv+rG551123eFwBhCMde6BIS90c3AAAAA='), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('base64', '-d'), stdin=echo.stdout)
echo.wait()

print(output)
```

Comment: thank you!!! Both example work!